# How to analyze bundles created by angular cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to analyze the bundles created by angular cli to see what's actually included my module to allow for optimization of the bundle size.

What would be the best way to do this?

A good project I found is:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer for the generated chunks. It gives you a nice tree overview of the components you are using.